# MKMapView Delegate Methods not working

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates, mkmapview

I just wanted to add a Polyline to my Map which is displayed in a tableviewcell. Unfortunately
the delegate methods are not called... Would be nice if someone knows why.

My tableview.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Route.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface RoutesDetailView : UITableViewController<MKMapViewDelegate>{
    Route *myRoute;
    MKMapView *mapView;
    // the view we create for the line on the map
    MKPolylineView* _routeLineView;

    // the rect that bounds the loaded points
    MKMapRect _routeRect;
    MKPolyline* _routeLine;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Route *myRoute;
@property (nonatomic,retain) MKMapView *mapView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MKPolyline* routeLine;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MKPolylineView* routeLineView;

-(MKPolyline *) loadRoute: (Route *) theRoute;
@end
```

And my tableview.m:

```
    @implementation RoutesDetailView
    @synthesize myRoute,mapView;
    @synthesize routeLine = _routeLine;
    @synthesize routeLineView = _routeLineView;

    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
    {
        self = [super initWithStyle:style];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    #pragma mark - View lifecycle

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {    
        [super viewDidLoad];
        MKMapView *myMap = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 1, 300 , 300)];
        myMap.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
        [self setMapView:myMap];
        [mapView setDelegate:self];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D annotationCoord;
        annotationCoord.latitude = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",NSLocalizedString(@"DefaultPointLAT", nil)] doubleValue];
        annotationCoord.longitude = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",NSLocalizedString(@"DefaultPointLONG", nil)] doubleValue];
        MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
        annotationPoint.coordinate = annotationCoord;
        MKCoordinateRegion region =
        MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance (annotationPoint.coordinate,[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",NSLocalizedString(@"DefaultCircle", nil)] doubleValue], [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",NSLocalizedString(@"DefaultCircle", nil)] doubleValue]);
        [mapView setRegion:region animated:NO];
        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    }

    - (void)viewDidUnload
    {
        [super viewDidUnload];
        // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
        // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    }

    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    }

    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    }

    - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    }

    - (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    }

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
        // Return YES for supported orientations
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    }

    #pragma mark - Table view data source


    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
.
.
.

            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellMap";
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            [mapView setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 1, cell.frame.size.width-20 , cell.frame.size.height-1)];
            [cell addSubview:mapView];
            [mapView addOverlay:[self loadRoute:myRoute]];
            return cell;
.
.
.

    }




    #pragma mark - Table view delegate
    -(MKPolyline *) loadRoute: (Route *) theRoute
    {

        MKMapPoint northEastPoint;
        MKMapPoint southWestPoint; 

        // create a c array of points.
        MKMapPoint* pointArr = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * theRoute.latitude.count);

        for(int idx = 0; idx < theRoute.latitude.count; idx++)
        {

            CLLocationDegrees latitude = [[[theRoute latitude] objectAtIndex:idx] doubleValue];
            CLLocationDegrees longitude = [[[theRoute longitude] objectAtIndex:idx] doubleValue];

            // create our coordinate and add it to the correct spot in the array
            CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);

            MKMapPoint point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinate);

            //
            // adjust the bounding box
            //

            // if it is the first point, just use them, since we have nothing to compare to yet.
            if (idx == 0) {
                northEastPoint = point;
                southWestPoint = point;
            }
            else
            {
                if (point.x > northEastPoint.x)
                    northEastPoint.x = point.x;
                if(point.y > northEastPoint.y)
                    northEastPoint.y = point.y;
                if (point.x < southWestPoint.x)
                    southWestPoint.x = point.x;
                if (point.y < southWestPoint.y)
                    southWestPoint.y = point.y;
            }

            pointArr[idx] = point;

        }

        // create the polyline based on the array of points.
        self.routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:pointArr count:theRoute.latitude.count];

        _routeRect = MKMapRectMake(southWestPoint.x, southWestPoint.y, northEastPoint.x - southWestPoint.x, northEastPoint.y - southWestPoint.y);

        // clear the memory allocated earlier for the points
        free(pointArr);
        return self.routeLine;


    }

    - (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id )overlay
    {
        NSLog(@"DELEGATE CALL");
        MKOverlayView* overlayView = nil;

        if(overlay == self.routeLine)
        {
            //if we have not yet created an overlay view for this overlay, create it now.
            if(nil == self.routeLineView)
            {
                self.routeLineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:self.routeLine];
                self.routeLineView.fillColor = [UIColor redColor];
                self.routeLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
                self.routeLineView.lineWidth = 15;
            }

            overlayView = self.routeLineView;

        }

        return overlayView;

    }


    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
        /*
         <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
         // ...
         // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
         [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
         */
    }

    @end
```

Comment: Do you mean viewForOverlay is not called?  Log the latitude and longitude of each point added and make sure they are correct (not swapped, in range, etc).  Also, in the malloc you get sizeof CLLocationCoordinate2D but the array contains MKMapPoint structs.  Those two structs are not the same thing but they happen to have the same size so you don't see any issue.

Comment: Yes, the viewForOverlay is not called, the lat and longs are correct. This delegate method is perfectly working in another View Controller...but does not work in a uitableview cell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, I was having the same issue. After trying many combinations this is the one which works.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate> {

    MKMapView   *mapView;
}
```

and the implementation...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMakeFullScreenIphone];
    mapView.delegate = self;
    [mapView setMapType: MKMapTypeStandard];
    [self.view addSubview: mapView]; 


    MKCoordinateRegion newRegion;
    // configure region...
    [mapView setRegion:newRegion animated:YES];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    //configure coordinate...

    MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
    [annotation setCoordinate:coordinate];
    [annotation setTitle:@"TEST"];
    [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
}
```

The simple code above works fine and delegate's methods were called.

Answer (score 0):

> if you are running the application in simulator, then the

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id )overlay
```

this delegate method will not get called, **you need to run it on iOS Device.**

Answer (score 0):

The first Meth is

**mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:**

and the second is

**mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:**

**Header File**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *searchButton;

@end
```

**Implementation File**

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    self.searchButton.hidden = YES;
}

- (IBAction)setMapType:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
    switch (sender.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
            break;
        case 1:
            self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
            break;
        case 2:
            self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (IBAction)zoomToCurrentLocation:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    float spanX = 0.00725;
    float spanY = 0.00725;
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center.latitude = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    region.center.longitude = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = spanX;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = spanY;
    self.searchButton.hidden = YES;
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    self.searchButton.hidden = NO;
}

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {
    [self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:userLocation.coordinate animated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```